# Destructuring assignment within import statements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, es6-modules, javascript-import

According to <strike>this [source](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-destructuring-in-depth) and</strike> a vague memory of having seen this sort of usage in a project somewhere, I'm curious if anyone has been able to do the following:

```
import {map: { series }} from 'contra'
```

As stated on this [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) overview:

> The import statement in ES6 behaves similarly to destructuring, but it
>   is important to note that it is not actually destructuring.

It appears that imports work a little different and perhaps one cannot expect the same exact behavior, but I haven't been able to verify the status of this. Is what I am trying to do part of the official ECMAScript 6/7 spec?

In attempting to answer this, please kindly include (or link) the portion of the spec that clarifies this concern.

Comment: The MDN entry is somewhere between misleading and completely wrong. It should say, "The import statement in ES6 has a superficial resemblance to destructuring, but is actually completely unrelated."

Comment: @torazaburo: Maybe even only "The shorthand named import declaration…"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant portion of the spec is [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports).

An *ImportDeclaration* is

> **`import`** *ImportClause* *FromClause*;

If you examine *ImportClause*, you'll see it's just the familiar `* as Foo`, or `DefaultImport`, or `{ImportSpecifier, ...}`, etc., where *ImportSpecifier* is an *ImportBinding*, which in turn is a *BindingIdentifer*, which is just a plain old *Identifier*.

The MDN entry is somewhere between misleading and completely wrong. It should have said (and now does say):

> The import statement in ES6 has a superficial resemblance to destructuring, but is actually completely unrelated.

I find more and more incorrect and misleading information in MDN these days. It should be taken with a grain of salt. The authoritative reference is the spec.

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring assignment only when you're *assigning* variables. Imports are completely different thing and you can't use destructuring assignment with them.

You can instead use destructuring assignment with a direct `require()` call (assuming that you're using Node.js or RequireJS):

```
const {map: { series }} = require('contra')
```