# How to save destructured import as properties of one object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My scenario is that `@/helpers/filters` has functions A, B, C, D, E, F... and I only need A, B, C, and want to keep it inside 1 object `filters`, rather than as separate values A, B, C.

I can do it in two steps:

```
import {
    A, B, C
} from '@/helpers/filters';

let filters = {
    A, B, C
};
```

but would rather simplify it to something like:

```
import {
    A, B, C
} as filters from '@/helpers/filters';
```

but this syntax is highlited as "Expression statement is not assignment or call".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39376453/448144

Comment: `import` statement is supposed to be statically analyzed and supports only [this syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). If it's not there, you can be sure it's not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no syntax for doing that (currently). Your choices are:

1. Create a module (perhaps `@/helpers/abcfilters`) that imports just A, B, and C and then exports them:

   ```
   export { A, B, C } from '@/helpers/filters';
   ```

   ...and then use that module instead:

   ```
   import * as filters from '@/helpers/abcfilters';
   ```
2. Use `import * as filters from '@/helpers/filters';` and just don't use what you don't need.
3. Import A, B, and C individually. If you want to, after importing them, you can add their values to an object and then use that object, but beware that if you have any circular dependencies, the A, B, and C you receive initially may not have their final values yet. (And of course, even if you don't have circular references, module exports can be modified over time by the exporting module, though it's relatively rare to do that in practice.)

Comment: *just don't use what you don't need* - since this depends on the environment, there's a chance that unused filters won't be tree-shaken.

Comment: @estus - Yes, there is that chance, although as modules become native, the chance decreases... :-) Still, I really should move the last one to the top of the list, shouldn't it? (Edit: Done.)

Comment: Option nr 1 seems to be the cleanest, but would also add most overhead and move the dependencies of my module to other module (abcfilters) which would be less convenient to manage. Option nr 3 is basically just what I tried, right? Or I can mix it with nr 2 (import everything and add needed functions to Object, `filters = {a: filtersAll.a, b: filtersAll.b}`).

Comment: @van_folmert: I don't see the issues with #1 that you list; all modules have dependencies. I suppose it adds a layer, but nothing to worry about it. Yes, #2 is what you describe. You could combine #3 with #2 but arguably you'd be getting the worst of both worlds. :-)